# merge two object arrays with Angular 2 and TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, angular

I have gone across the JavaScript questions on this topic, this question is specifically about Angular2 with TypeScript.

What I am trying to do is to concatenate the json objects to an array.

My code looks something like this,

```
public results: [];


public getResults(){
    this._service.get_search_results(this._slug, this._next).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.results.concat(data.results);
                this._next = data.next;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
}
```

How can I concatenate `data.results` to `this.results` with typescript and  angular?

`this._slug` and `this._next` are set on class.

thanks.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

With angular 6 **spread operator** and **concat** not work. You can resolve it easy:

```
result.push(...data);
```

Comment: came here looking for a solution while maintaining object reference between methods. this worked perfectly. thank you

Comment: This doesn't merge the arrays, it adds data from the second into the first. While it can do the job, it's something to be careful of since it modifies the original array.

Comment: Perfect solution!

Comment: awesome, i had problem with 'concat' to an empty array, but adding 'result ??= [];' before this line make my code complete.

Comment: what is the use of ...

Answer (score 291):

The **spread operator** is kinda cool.

```
this.results = [ ...this.results, ...data.results];
```

---

> The spread operator allows you to easily place an expanded version of an array into another array.

[You can read about spread operator here.](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator)

Comment: Updated url for spread operator can be found here: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/spread-operator

Answer (score 148):

I think that you should use rather the following:

```
data => {
  this.results = this.results.concat(data.results);
  this._next = data.next;
},
```

From the `concat` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

> The concat() method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work with Uint8arrays :(

Comment: May fail if this.results is null or undefined

Answer (score 11):

> Assume i have two arrays. The first one has student details and the
> student marks details. Both arrays have the common key, that is
> ‘studentId’

```
let studentDetails = [
  { studentId: 1, studentName: 'Sathish', gender: 'Male', age: 15 },
  { studentId: 2, studentName: 'kumar', gender: 'Male', age: 16 },
  { studentId: 3, studentName: 'Roja', gender: 'Female', age: 15 },
  {studentId: 4, studentName: 'Nayanthara', gender: 'Female', age: 16},
];

let studentMark = [
  { studentId: 1, mark1: 80, mark2: 90, mark3: 100 },
  { studentId: 2, mark1: 80, mark2: 90, mark3: 100 },
  { studentId: 3, mark1: 80, mark2: 90, mark3: 100 },
  { studentId: 4, mark1: 80, mark2: 90, mark3: 100 },
];
```

> I want to merge the two arrays based on the key ‘studentId’. I have
> created a function to merge the two arrays.

```
const mergeById = (array1, array2) =>
    array1.map(itm => ({
      ...array2.find((item) => (item.studentId === itm.studentId) && item),
      ...itm
    }));
```

> here is the code to get the final result

`let result = mergeById(studentDetails, studentMark`);

```
[
{"studentId":1,"mark1":80,"mark2":90,"mark3":100,"studentName":"Sathish","gender":"Male","age":15},{"studentId":2,"mark1":80,"mark2":90,"mark3":100,"studentName":"kumar","gender":"Male","age":16},{"studentId":3,"mark1":80,"mark2":90,"mark3":100,"studentName":"Roja","gender":"Female","age":15},{"studentId":4,"mark1":80,"mark2":90,"mark3":100,"studentName":"Nayanthara","gender":"Female","age":16}
]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the form recommended by ES6:

```
data => {
  this.results = [
    ...this.results,
    data.results,
  ];
  this._next = data.next;
},
```

This works if you initialize your array first (`public results = [];`); otherwise replace `...this.results,` by `...this.results ? this.results : [],`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

**try this**

```
data => {
    this.results = [...this.results, ...data.results];
    this._next = data.next;
}
```