# Flatten an array of array and combine with another array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

According to [this](https://schneidenbach.gitbooks.io/typescript-cookbook/functional-programming/flattening-array-of-arrays.html) article you can flatten an array using concat.

For example;

```
const nestedArrays: Person[][] = [
    [
        {firstName: "Andrew", lastName: "Smith"},

    ],
    [
        {firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Cawlins"},
    ],
    [
        {firstName: "Susan", lastName: "Sarandon"},
    ]
]
```

will can be converted to

```
const flattenedArray: Person[] = [
    {firstName: "Andrew", lastName: "Smith"},
    {firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Cawlins"},
    {firstName: "Susan", lastName: "Sarandon"},
]
```

by using

```
const flattenedArray = [].concat(...nestedArrays);
```

I have an additional array like the follows,

```
const additional = ["extra1", "extra2"];
```

My end result should be

```
[
 ["extra1", "extra2"],
 [{firstName: "Andrew", lastName: "Smith"}],
 [{firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Cawlins"}],
 [{firstName: "Susan", lastName: "Sarandon"}],
]
```

Can I achieve that using concat in typescript? Or is there another method that I would be using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge two object arrays with Angular 2 and TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092458/merge-two-object-arrays-with-angular-2-and-typescript)

Comment: The difference is if I use additional.concat(nestedArray), it would end up in something like ["extra1", "extra2", <rest of the things>] which I do not want in this case

Comment: How about if you define `const additional = [["extra1", "extra2"]];`

Comment: The result is still array of arrays, so I don't see a reason for flattening. `const flattenedArray = [additional].concat(nestedArrays);`

Comment: Both the above suggestions work ```const additional = [["extra1", "extra2"]];``` and ```const flattenedArray = [additional].concat(nestedArrays);```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to flatten anything just use [unshift](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_array_unshift.htm) to prepend:

```
const nestedArrays: Person[][] = [
    [
        {firstName: "Andrew", lastName: "Smith"},

    ],
    [
        {firstName: "Chris", lastName: "Cawlins"},
    ],
    [
        {firstName: "Susan", lastName: "Sarandon"},
    ]
]
const additional = ["extra1", "extra2"];
const combination = nestedArrays.unshift(additional);
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but that would probably result in TypeScript compilation error because the `additional` array is not Person type. It will probably have to be changed to `any[][]` type