# How to merge two different arrays of object in one single array Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

i am calling two api at same time and getting below response in array1 and array2.at
Now i wanted to merge all the object in one array

Below is my array1 and array2 response.

```
Const Array1 = [
    {
        "lineLossId": 1,
        "dataSource": "DFOS",
        "category": "Dressings",
        "entryDetails": {
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2023"
        },                
        "HrDbMonth": null
    },
    {
        "lineLossId": 2,
        "dataSource": "DFOS",
        "entryDetails": {
            "month": "August",
            "year": "2023"
        },                
        "HrDbMonth": null
    }
];


const array2 = [
    {
        "lineLossId": 3,
        "dataSource": "DFOS",
        "category": "Dressings",
        "entryDetails": {
            "month": "August",
            "year": 2023
        },
        "uom": "OOOUnits"
        
    }
];
```

I am expecting all the response to be merge in one array with all objects and in sequential index key.

**Below is my Expected output**

```
Const array3 = [
    {
        "lineLossId": 1,
        "dataSource": "DFOS",
        "category": "Dressings",
        "entryDetails": {
            "month": "September",
            "year": "2023"
        },                
        "HrDbMonth": null
    },
    {
        "lineLossId": 2,
        "dataSource": "DFOS",
        "entryDetails": {
            "month": "August",
            "year": "2023"
        },                
        "HrDbMonth": null
    },
    {
        "lineLossId": 3,
        "dataSource": "DFOS",
        "category": "Dressings",
        "entryDetails": {
            "month": "August",
            "year": 2023
        },
        "uom": "OOOUnits"
        
    }
];
```

Comment: Merging two arrays is easy. What you tried and what problems have you faced?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge two object arrays with Angular 2 and TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092458/merge-two-object-arrays-with-angular-2-and-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To concat 2 arrays, you can use (as the name suggests) the  `.concat()` function like this.

```js
const foo = [1, 2];
const bar = [3];
const concatedArray = foo.concat(bar) //--> [1,2,3]
```

To sort the array afterwards, you can use the `.sort()` function.

```js
const arrayOfObjects = [
  { id: 3, name: 'Alice' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Charlie' },
];

// Sort the array by the 'id' property
arrayOfObjects.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);

console.log(arrayOfObjects);

// output
//[
//  { id: 1, name: 'Bob' },
//  { id: 2, name: 'Charlie' },
//  { id: 3, name: 'Alice' }
//]
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need call to two (or more) diferents APIs and one is not depending another, you use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) rxjs operator to have an unique subscription. after use [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator to return the join of the two response. You can also use sort method of the array to be sure the response get the array sorted:

```
getData()
{
  return forkJoin([
       this.httpClient.get(...),
       this.httpClient.get(...)]
     ).
     pipe.pipe(
        map(([res1, res2]: [any[], any[]]) =>
        res1.concat(res2)
            .sort((a: any, b: any) => a.lineLossId - b.lineLossId)
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With ES6 you can do it easily as below,

```
let mergedarray = [...array1, ...array2];
```

**Output:**

```
[{
  "lineLossId": 1,
  "dataSource": "DFOS",
  "category": "Dressings",
  "entryDetails": {
    "month": "September",
    "year": "2023"
  },
  "HrDbMonth": null
},
{
  "lineLossId": 2,
  "dataSource": "DFOS",
  "entryDetails": {
    "month": "August",
    "year": "2023"
  },
  "HrDbMonth": null
},
{
  "lineLossId": 3,
  "dataSource": "DFOS",
  "category": "Dressings",
  "entryDetails": {
    "month": "August",
    "year": 2023
  },
  "uom": "OOOUnits"
}]
```

**NOTE: It is nothing related to Angular.**